# Cannot find Axis 1.4 for Download

Tags: web-services, axis

I was hoping to download Apache Axis from this location http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/axis/1_4

but it turns out that all the mirrors listed there show me

```
Not Found

The requested URL /mirror/ws/axis/1_4 was not found on this server.
```

Is the library no longer available for download?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Visit the backup site mirror. i.e 
http://www.us.apache.org/dist/ws/

and click on the "older releases" link i.e. http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws and browse to the axis/1.4 folder.

Answer (score 7):

The Following Link takes you to the download page for the apache axis 1.4  distribution
vist the link   http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis/1_4/

Answer (score 1):

For Downloading Axis 1.4 Final click on given link

http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache/axis/axis/java/1.4/